# Resolve Conflict:1 Shift Reduce in yacc program

Tags: compiler-warnings, yacc

I'm trying to execute a yacc program in ubuntu terminal for expression 2+6*9.The correct output should be 56 but i'm getting 2 as the output.Please help

```
<i>
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%token DIGIT
%%
S:E'\n' {printf("%d\n",$1);
            return 1;
            }
  ;
E:E'+'T {$$ - $1 + $3;}
  |T
  ;
T:T'*'T {$$ = $1 * $3;}
  |F
  ;
F:'('E')' {$$ = $2;}
  |DIGIT
;
%%
yylex()
{
 int c;
c = getchar();
if(isdigit(c))
{
 yylval = c- '0';
 return DIGIT;
}
return c;
}
main()
{
 printf("enter the expression");
yyparse();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find where you posted the information about the shift-reduce conflict. I'm trying to find where you posted the information about the shift-reduce conflict. You're going to have to include the relevant debug output.

Comment: You are going to need to use association here to control the precedence of the operators (or create more rules perhaps).

Comment: So the shift/reduce conflict is in your title but has nothing to do with the question? What's the point?

Comment: @leppie The grammar already expresses operator precedence, with terms and factors in different productions.

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect output is due to the action:

```
E:E'+'T {$$ - $1 + $3;}
```

this never sets the value of `$$`, so you get the default value from the stack (`$1`).  Change the `-` to `=` to actually assign to `$$`.

That leaves the shift/reduce conflict.  You can use the `-v` flag to yacc to get a listing of the state machine in `y.output`, giving you more details on what exactly the conflicts are.  In this case, it comes from the rule:

```
T:T'*'T
```

which is ambiguous -- multiplies can be combined either left-recursively or right recursively (so an input like `2*3*4` can be parsed as either (2×3)×4 or 2×(3×4) ).  The defauult shift resolution parses left-recursive (which is correct), but in fact its irrelevant as multiplication is associative.  You can fix the conflict by changing the rule to left-recursive:

```
T:T'*'F
```